# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen after initrd on imac5,1

Tags: boot, system-installation, mac

Ubuntu 20.04 on imac5,1 (Intel Core 2 Duo, late 2006).
Installed from external USB hard drive made from `ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` with `bootia32.efi` added.

Can hold right shift to get in to `grub` menu.
Therefore I don't think it's an EFI or `grub` problem.

Adding `nomodeset` makes no difference (ATI Radeon X1600).

Adding an `echo` at the end of the script shows on screen therefore it can't be hanging in the script.

Gets stuck on a black screen; nothing happens.

**Update:**

The machine (which seems to be a bit of a lemon) has 32-bit EFI which is why the `.efi` file needs to be replaced; it won't boot as standard.

Tried the 64-bit `boot-repair-disk` which again requires `bootia32.efi` to be added to it after making an external USB disc with Rufus. After a long wait on a black screen it eventually loaded. It goes in a loop asking to be updated, but after declining it did something and generated this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nWGrxtMvPV/

Have done *recommended repair* which did *purge and reinstall of GRUB on sda2* and asked me to enter three commands into a terminal -- which I did. Then forward to another command, then it created another report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FGp53696Wm/

It mentioned:

> Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file)!

On rebooting I get

```
error: file `/boot/grub/i386-efi/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

`rEFInd` has the same two options as described in the original post.

In grub rescue I tried:

```
set root=(hd1,gpt2)
set prefix=(hd1,gpt2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
```

but

> ``` error: file ``/boot/grub/i386-efi/normal.mod' not found ```
> Indeed there is no such directory, but there is an `x86_64-efi` directory.
> Gut feeling is that it's the 32-bit one that this machine will need.

Comment: You probably don't need the 32bit boot programme unless you are trying the Matt Gadient special https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/ so I would make a bootable USB with boot-repair on it and let it do it's thing. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Looks like this broke it even more by replacing the 32-bit EFI things with the 64-bit ones that definitely don't work on this machine. I'm not convinced that EFI was the problem, though, because the black screen seemed to be coming up _after_ `initrd`?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Short answer: no. Works with Debian 10 without X11 (except that you can't turn the backlight off), so I think it is an X11 problem.